# Python script works from one folder but not on subfolders.

Tags: python, multiprocessing, directory

Good evening everyone,

I am trying to do some machine learning with python so I imported the module scikit-learn:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
```

And it gives me this strange error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-22-b55a4eaccb0b>", line 1, in <module>
    from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

  File "C:\Users\Francesco\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from ._function_transformer import FunctionTransformer

  File "C:\Users\Francesco\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_function_transformer.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ..utils import check_array

  File "C:\Users\Francesco\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from ..externals.joblib import cpu_count

  File "C:\Users\Francesco\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\__init__.py", line 128, in <module>
    from .parallel import Parallel

  File "C:\Users\Francesco\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ._multiprocessing_helpers import mp

  File "C:\Users\Francesco\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\_multiprocessing_helpers.py", line 24, in <module>
    _sem = mp.Semaphore()

AttributeError: module 'multiprocessing' has no attribute 'Semaphore'
```

The errors are copied from Anaconda (Spider) but they are present even by starting a python session from the command line. The folder where I run the script is:

```
C:\Users\Francesco\Desktop\script_python
```

The **very strange thing** is that if I run the same script from the Desktop, just a folder up, it works!

```
C:\Users\Francesco\Desktop\ <-- Here it works!!
```

I found out that the problem is relative to the multiprocessing module, here a snapshot of this strange behavior:

[image: Summary of the problem]

Comment: Do you have any directory named `multiprocessing` on the Desktop (that hides the `multiprocessing` module). You can try doing `python -c "import multiprocessing; print(multiprocessing.__dir__)"`

Comment: Oh god I had a module named multiprocessing in that folder and I completely forgot! Great, post it as an answer I will accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a module `multiprocessing` in the directory where you are running the script from.

Generally, in Python, the path where you run your script has precedence over the Python env, so it will try to pick that one first. This means that when `sklearn` imports `multiprocessing`, it uses your module, and not the built-in `multiprocessing`.

When this type of error appears, one way to identify the error is to run

```
python -c "import multiprocessing; print(multiprocessing.__dir__)"
```

to double check which module is being used.